# How to keep directory structure in Vite build?

Tags: typescript, build, vite, rollup

I have a Vite library with the following structure:

[image]

And the following vite config:

```js
export default defineConfig(() => ({
  base: './',
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths(), dts({ rollupTypes: true })],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      fileName: 'index',
      name: '@shared/frontend',
    },
  },
  test: {
    include: ['src/**/*.{spec,test}.{j,t}s?(x)'],
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: 'src/setupTests.ts',
    clearMocks: true,
    coverage: {
      provider: 'istanbul',
      enabled: true,
      100: true,
      reporter: ['text', 'html'],
      reportsDirectory: 'coverage',
    },
  },
}));
```

And this defined in `package.json`:

```json
  "name": "@shared/frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "main": "./dist/index.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.mjs",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/index.umd.js"
    }
  },
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
```

When I run build, I expect the output `dist` to be in the same structure of the source (albeit divided into `.js` and `.d.ts` files. Instead, I get a single consolidated file like so:

[image]

What I expect is to have a structure like:

```
- dist
- - index.mjs
- - index.umd.js
- - utils.d.ts
- - utils.js
- - configs
- - hermes
```

Or something to that effect.

I tried using the manual chunks plugin for rollup but that didn't actually make any difference. I just don't know what this is even called in order to look it up.